# Multiple entities are not added to fields that are entity collection data types

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I use Spring Boot, JPA, Spring Data JPA, QueryDSL and I am using Thymeleaf as the template engine. The logic I came up with is, like YouTube comments, when I added BigComments and then I look up PostInfo, I wanted to look up BigComments in the ListBigCommentsList field of the BigComments class. However, once I added BigComments, it seems to work properly, but if I added it several times, it is not saved in the ListBigCommentsList field of the BigComments class. And curiously, when saving a new PostComments entity, the object that I tried to saved the previously BigComments entity in the first PostComments object, it is being saved in the List bigCommentsList field that second object of PostComments. It's working really weirdly. I need your help.

---

**Entity codes**

**PostInfo**

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;

import My_Project.integration.entity.Dto.PostInfoDto;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class PostInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_number")
    private Long postNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Users postedUser;

    @Column(name = "post_title", length = 50, nullable = false)
    public String postTitle;

    @Column(name = "post_content", nullable = false)
    public String postContent;

    @Embedded
    public Dates dates;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "postInfo",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private Set<Photo> photo = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "postInfo"
    )
    @BatchSize(size = 1000)
    private Set<PostComments> comments;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn
    @JsonIgnore
    private PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike;

    public PostInfo(Long postNumber, Users postedUser, String postTitle, String postContent, Dates dates, Set<Photo> photo, Set<PostComments> comments, PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike) {
        this.postNumber = postNumber;
        this.postedUser = postedUser;
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
        this.postContent = postContent;
        this.dates = dates;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.postLikeAndDislike = postLikeAndDislike;
    }

    public PostInfo() {
    }

    public void addPhoto(Photo photo) {
        this.photo.add(photo);

        if(photo.getPostInfo() != this)
            photo.setPostInfoByPostInfo(this);
    }

    public PostInfo(Users users, PostInfoDto postInfo,PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike) {
        Dates dates = new Dates(
                LocalDateTime.now(),LocalDateTime.now()
        );
        this.postedUser = users;
        this.postTitle = postInfo.getPostTitle();
        this.postContent = postInfo.getPostContent();
        this.dates = dates;
        this.comments = new HashSet<>();
        setPostLikeAndDislike(postLikeAndDislike);
    }

    public void addComments(PostComments postComments) {
        this.comments.add(postComments);
        postComments.setPostInfo(this);
    }
}
```

**PostComments**

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;

import My_Project.integration.entity.Dto.CommentDto;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class PostComments {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_comments_number")
    private Long commentNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private PostInfo postInfo;

    @Column(name = "post_commented_users_email")
    private String postCommentedUsersEmail;

    @Column(name = "post_comments_contents", nullable = false)
    private String postCommentsContents;

    @Embedded
    private Dates dates;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "bigCommentsNumber",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<BigComments> bigCommentsList = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn
    private PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike;

    public PostComments(CommentDto commentDto,PostInfo postInfo,PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike) {
        this.postInfo = postInfo;
        this.postCommentedUsersEmail = commentDto.getUsers_email();
        this.postCommentsContents = commentDto.getComment();
        this.postLikeAndDislike = new PostLikeAndDislike();

        Dates dates1 = new Dates(LocalDateTime.now(),LocalDateTime.now());
        this.dates = dates1;
    }

    public PostComments(Long commentNumber, PostInfo postInfo, String postCommentedUsersEmail, String postCommentsContents, Dates dates, List<BigComments> bigCommentsList, PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike) {
        this.commentNumber = commentNumber;
        this.postInfo = postInfo;
        this.postCommentedUsersEmail = postCommentedUsersEmail;
        this.postCommentsContents = postCommentsContents;
        this.dates = dates;
        this.bigCommentsList = new ArrayList<>(bigCommentsList);
        this.postLikeAndDislike = postLikeAndDislike;
    }

    public PostComments() {
        this.bigCommentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Integer bigCommentSize() {
        return getBigCommentsList().size();
    }

    public void addBigComments(BigComments bigComments) {
        this.bigCommentsList.add(bigComments);
        bigComments.setPostComments(this);
    }
}
```

**BigComments**

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Setter
public class BigComments {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "big_comments_number")
    private Long bigCommentsNumber;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "users")
    private Users bigCommentedUser;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_comments_number")
    private PostComments postComments;

    @Column(name = "big_comments_content",nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @OneToOne(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(name="lidi")
    private PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike;

    @Embedded
    private Dates dates;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="postInfo")
    private PostInfo postInfo;
}
```

**PostLikeAndDislike**

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class PostLikeAndDislike {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "postLikeAndDislike")
    PostInfo postInfo;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "postLikeAndDislike",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<Liked> liked = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "postLikeAndDislike",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<DisLiked> disLiked = new HashSet<>();

    public void setPostInfo1(PostInfo postInfo) {
        this.postInfo = postInfo;
        postInfo.setPostLikeAndDislike(this);
    }
}
```

**Liked**

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Liked {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Users users;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn
    private PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike;
}
```

**DisLiked**

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class DisLiked {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Users users;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike;
}
```

**Users**

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;


import My_Project.integration.entity.Dto.UserInfoDto;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Setter
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ssn","phone_number"})})
public class Users {

    @Column(name = "email", length = 40, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Id
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", length = 12, nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name =  "ssn", length = 13, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String ssn;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "point")
    private Long point;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "postedUser")
    private List<PostInfo> uploadedPost = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
    private List<PointHistory> pointHistories = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    private Dates dates;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "users"
    )
    private Set<Liked> liked = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "users"
    )
    private Set<DisLiked> disLiked = new HashSet<>();


    public Users(UserInfoDto userInfoDto){
        this.setEmail(userInfoDto.getEmail());
        this.setPassword(userInfoDto.getPassword());
        this.setPhoneNumber(userInfoDto.getPhone_number());
        this.setSsn(userInfoDto.getSsn());
        this.setPoint(0L);
        this.setName(userInfoDto.getName());

        Address address = new Address(
                userInfoDto.getCity_name(),
                userInfoDto.getTown_name(),
                userInfoDto.getStreet_name(),
                userInfoDto.getZip_code(),
                userInfoDto.getDetails()
        );

        this.setAddress(address);

        List<PostInfo> postInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PointHistory> pointHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();

        this.setUploadedPost(postInfoList);
        this.setPointHistories(pointHistoryList);

        Dates dates = new Dates(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());

        this.setDates(dates);
    }

}
```

---

**Controller code**

```
@PostMapping("/find_post/addBigComments")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addBigComments(
            @RequestBody addBigCommentsDto addBigCommentsDto,
            @CookieValue("users") Optional<Cookie> cookie) {
        if (!cookie.isPresent()) {
            return "not_logined";
        }

        postService.addBigComments(addBigCommentsDto, cookie.get().getValue());
        return "success";
    }
```

---

**Service code**

```
 @Transactional
    public void addBigComments(addBigCommentsDto addBigCommentsDto, String s) {
        try {
            PostComments postCommentsV3 = postCommentsRepository.findPostCommentsV3(addBigCommentsDto.getComment_number()).get();
            Users users = usersRepository.findUsersByEmail(s).get();
            PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike =
                    PostLikeAndDislike
                            .builder()
                            .postInfo(postCommentsV3.getPostInfo())
                            .disLiked(new HashSet<>())
                            .liked(new HashSet<>())
                            .build();

            postLikeAndDislikeRepository.save(postLikeAndDislike);

            BigComments build = BigComments.builder()
                    .dates(new Dates(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now()))
                    .bigCommentedUser(users)
                    .postComments(postCommentsV3)
                    .content(addBigCommentsDto.getComment())
                    .postLikeAndDislike(postLikeAndDislike)
                    .postInfo(postCommentsV3.getPostInfo())
                    .build();
            postCommentsV3.addBigComments(build);


            bigCommentsRepository.save(build);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("NPE 발생, 회원 조회 or 댓글 조회 실패");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

**Repository Code**

```
 public Optional<PostComments> findPostCommentsV3(Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(jpaQueryFactory
                .selectFrom(postComments)
                .join(postComments.postInfo, postInfo).fetchJoin()
                .join(postComments.postLikeAndDislike, postLikeAndDislike).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(postComments.bigCommentsList, bigComments).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(bigComments.postLikeAndDislike).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(bigComments.postInfo).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(bigComments.postComments).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(bigComments.bigCommentedUser, users).fetchJoin()
                .where(postComments.commentNumber.eq(id))
                .fetchOne());
    }
```

---

**PostComments saving code (Controller + Service)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register_comments", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String registerComments(
            @RequestBody CommentDto commentDto,
            @CookieValue(name = "users") Optional<Cookie> cookie,
            RedirectAttributes attr) {
        try {
            postService.registerComments(commentDto, cookie);
            attr.addAttribute("id", commentDto.getPost_number());
            return "redirect:/find_post";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            attr.addAttribute("string", "로그인 후 댓글을 작성 해 주세요");
            return "redirect:/alert";
        }
```

```
@Transactional
    public Boolean registerComments(CommentDto commentDto, Optional<Cookie> cookie) throws Exception{
        try {
            Optional<PostInfo> post = findPostV2(commentDto.getPost_number());
            PostLikeAndDislike postLikeAndDislike = PostLikeAndDislike.builder().postInfo(post.get()).build();
            postLikeAndDislikeRepository.save(postLikeAndDislike);

            PostComments postComments = new PostComments(commentDto, post.get(),postLikeAndDislike);
            postCommentsRepository.save(postComments);

            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("로그인 되어있지 않습니다 or 조회 불가능");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new NullPointerException("NPE 발생");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("에러 발생");
        }
    }
```

---

**the part of the problem occurs**
**The part that looks up PostInfo (Controller + Service + Repository)**

```
@GetMapping("/find_post")
    public String findPost(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model, @CookieValue("users") Optional<Cookie> cookie) {
        try {
            PageRequest of = PageRequest.of(0, 10);

            PostInfo postInfo = postService.findPostV2(id).get();
            Slice<PostCommentsResponseDto> commentsV2 = postService.findCommentsV2(postInfo, of);
            PostDto post = new PostDto(postInfo);

            if (cookie.isPresent()) { // 로그인 되어 있을 시
                Optional<Users> usersOptional = userService.findById(cookie.get().getValue());
                model.addAttribute("checked", post.checkLikeAndDisLike(usersOptional));
            }

            model.addAttribute("post", post);
            model.addAttribute("time", LocalDateTime.now());
            return "copy_post";
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            model.addAttribute("string", e.toString());
            return "alert";
        }
    }
```

```
@Transactional
    public Optional<PostInfo> findPostV2(Long id) throws NoSuchElementException {
        return postRepository.findPostInfo(id);
    }
```

```
@Transactional
    public Slice<PostCommentsResponseDto> findCommentsV2(PostInfo postInfo,Pageable pageable) throws NoSuchElementException{

        return postCommentsRepository.findCommentsWithPaging(postInfo, pageable);
    }
```

```
public Slice<PostCommentsResponseDto> findCommentsWithPaging(PostInfo postInfo1, Pageable pageable) {
           List<PostCommentsResponseDto> fetch = jpaQueryFactory
                    .select(Projections.constructor(
                            PostCommentsResponseDto.class,
                            postComments
                    ))
                .from(postComments)
                .leftJoin(postComments.postInfo, postInfo).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(postComments.postLikeAndDislike, postLikeAndDislike).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(postLikeAndDislike.disLiked, disLiked).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(postLikeAndDislike.liked, liked).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(postLikeAndDislike.postInfo).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(postComments.bigCommentsList, bigComments).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(bigComments.bigCommentedUser).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(bigComments.postComments).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(bigComments.postInfo).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(bigComments.postLikeAndDislike).fetchJoin()
                .where(postComments.postInfo.eq(postInfo1))
                .fetch();

        return checkEndPage(pageable,fetch);
    }

    public Slice<PostCommentsResponseDto> checkEndPage(Pageable pageable, List<PostCommentsResponseDto> results) {
        boolean hasNext = false;

        if (results.size() > pageable.getPageSize()) {
            hasNext = true;
            results.remove(pageable.getPageSize());
        }
        return new SliceImpl<>(results,pageable,hasNext);
    }
```

```
@Override
    public Optional<PostInfo> findPostInfo(Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(
                jpaQueryFactory
                        .selectFrom(postInfo)
                        .join(postInfo.postedUser, users).fetchJoin()
                        .join(postInfo.photo, photo).fetchJoin()
                        .leftJoin(photo.postInfo).fetchJoin()
                        .join(postInfo.postLikeAndDislike, postLikeAndDislike).fetchJoin()
                        .leftJoin(postLikeAndDislike.liked, liked).fetchJoin()
                        .leftJoin(postLikeAndDislike.disLiked, disLiked).fetchJoin()
                        .leftJoin(postLikeAndDislike.postInfo).fetchJoin()
                        .where(postInfo.postNumber.eq(id))
                        .fetchOne()
        );
    }
```

I think the queryDSL part is going well. However, the problem is that when I run the find_post method (when looking up PostInfo), when I save bigComments, it seems that several sizes are saved as 2 in the bigCommentsList, but when looking up, postComments1.bigCommentsList().size() = 1, postComments2.bigCommentsList().size() = 1
So cannot be saved multiple times.

Comment: would you please define where specifically you are facing the issue? there are so many relationships defined in your code! perhaps make it shorter and cleaner? or check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for better improvment

Comment: @MohammedFataka I'm sorry. I think you must have been embarrassed by my poor English and questioning skills.I modified the post and added some more code. If you have a chance, please check it out. thank you very much